# How to return the bounding box for the (row, column) position of a canvas as a tuple of grid

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, grid

I am trying to write a code which will finally look like this:
[image]

Canvases are just a sea of pixels, so all I am trying to do is adding a little bit extra functionality
to make navigating that sea easier. Later on I'll be drawing rectangles (well, squares) onto the
canvas to represent the entities.

To do that I need a top left and a bottom right pixel coordinate.
So get_bbox allows translation from an instance of the Position(x,y) class (which is what we like to work
with because its stored in our grids dictionary) to these pixel coordinates, allowing us to easily work with the canvas like its a grid.

```
class AbstractGrid(tk.Canvas):
    
    def __init__(self, master, rows, cols, width, height, **kwargs):
        """

        master: The window in which the grid should be drawn. 
        rows: The integer number of rows in the grid.
        cols: The integer number of columns in the grid.
        width: The width of the grid canvas (in pixels). 
        height: The height of the grid canvas (in pixels). 
        **kwargs: Any other additional named parameters appropriate to tk.Canvas.
        """
        master=self._master
        rows=self._rows
        cols=self._cols
        width=self._width
        height=self._height

        super().__init__(master, rows, cols, width, height, **kwargs)  
        
    def get_bbox(self, position):
        """
        Returns the bounding box for the (row, column) position;
        this is a tuple containing information about the pixel positions of the edges of the shape,
        in the form (x min, y min, x max, y max).

        """
```

I am not sure how to write this get_bbox function.Would you please help me by giving a way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple maths:

```py
class AbstractGrid(tk.Canvas):

    def __init__(self, master, rows, cols, width, height, **kwargs):
        """

        master: The window in which the grid should be drawn.
        rows: The integer number of rows in the grid.
        cols: The integer number of columns in the grid.
        width: The width of the grid canvas (in pixels).
        height: The height of the grid canvas (in pixels).
        **kwargs: Any other additional named parameters appropriate to tk.Canvas.
        """
        super().__init__(master, width=width, height=height, **kwargs)

        self._rows = rows
        self._cols = cols
        self._width = width
        self._height = height
        # calculate the grid width and height
        self._grid_w = width / cols
        self._grid_h = height / rows

    def get_bbox(self, position):
        """
        Returns the bounding box for the (row, column) position;
        this is a tuple containing information about the pixel positions of the edges of the shape,
        in the form (x min, y min, x max, y max).

        """
        row, col = position
        x, y = col*self._grid_w, row*self._grid_h
        return x, y, x+self._grid_w, y+self._grid_h
```

Note that I have fixed issues on the following lines inside `__init__()`:

```py
        master=self._master # self.master is created implicitly
        rows=self._rows     # should swap LHS and RHS on these four lines
        cols=self._cols
        width=self._width
        height=self._height
```

Note also that if you want to have *square* grid, better specify the individual grid size instead of `rows`, `cols`.